# How to return list of exception in single exception?

Tags: java

I have an array of employees' ages. I want a list of invalid ages. I am trying to do it but I am not able to get it. I also create custom exception but it throws only current invalid age not all.

```
public class InvalidAgeException extends Exception {

    public InvalidAgeException(String str) {
        super(str);
    }
}


public class MainClass {

    public static void checkAge(int ages[]) throws InvalidAgeException {
        for (int i = 0; i < ages.length; i++) {
            try {
                if (ages[i] < 18) {
                    throw new InvalidAgeException(ages[i] + " invalid age");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(ages[i] + " valid age");
                }
            } catch (InvalidAgeException e) {

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidAgeException {
        int[] ages = { 19, 20, 24, 13, 27, 14 };
        checkAge(ages);
    }
}
```

**I want output like '13 is invalid age, 14 is invalid age'**

Comment: That is not a good use of exceptions - the whole method's point is to check the age, a failed check is expected, not exceptional.

Comment: Also, I think you want the `try/catch` to be in `main`.

Comment: Theoretically you could give your custom exception class a field to store those and add some methods to fill the field with data. But yeah, they are the wrong tool for this.

Comment: Store all invalid ages in a list, when the loop end, check the list is empty, if not throw an exception with the invalid ages

Comment: When an error occurs, just return `Arrays.toString(ages)` with an explanation.  If you don't want the `[]` that come with that, use `String.substring()` to return only the desired part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Explanation

Exceptions are clearly the wrong tool for this. Do not use them for regular control flow, only to indicate exceptional situations. In a `checkAge` method, an invalid age is clearly an expected situation, not exceptional.

A detailed discussion about this topic can be found here: [Are exceptions as control flow considered a serious antipattern? If so why?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why)

---

### Solution

That being said, just maintain some `List<Integer>` in which you collect the invalid ages, then print them afterwards:

```
public static void checkAge(int[] ages) {
    List<Integer> invalidAges = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ages.length; i++) {
        if (ages[i] < 18) {
            invalidAges.add(ages[i]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(ages[i] + " valid age");
        }
    }

    // Print invalid ages
    for (int invalidAge : invalidAges) {
        System.out.println(invalidAge + " is invalid age");
    }
}
```

You can of course also just print while you are iterating, no list needed:

```
public static void checkAge(int[] ages) {
    for (int age : ages) {
        if (age < 18) {
            System.out.println(age + " invalid age");
        } else {
            System.out.println(age + " valid age");
        }
    }
}
```

Or maybe collect into two different lists and then print them individually:

```
public static void checkAge(int[] ages) {
    List<Integer> validAges = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> invalidAges = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int age : ages) {
        if (age < 18) {
            invalidAges.add(age);
        } else {
            validAges.add(age);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Valid ages are:");
    validAges.forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("Invalid ages are:");
    invalidAges.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

If you are only interested in the invalid ages and want to explore Javas Stream API, what about this compact one-liner:

```
public static void checkAge(int[] ages) {
    IntStream.of(ages)
        .filter(age -> age < 18)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Whatever you prefer.

---

To address the original question for the sake of Q&A, in order to do this with exceptions, you would first collect into a `List` as shown and afterwards throw the exception, with all the collected values.

```
public class InvalidAgesException extends IllegalArgumentException {
    private final List<Integer> invalidAges;

    public InvalidAgesException(List<Integer> invalidAges) {
        this.invalidAges = invalidAges;
    }

    public List<Integer> getInvalidAges() {
        return invalidAges;
    }
}

public static void checkAge(int[] ages) {
    List<Integer> invalidAges = IntStream.of(ages)
        .filter(age -> age < 18)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    throw new InvalidAgesException(invalidAges);
}
```

Not that it makes any sense for your particular use case or anything. But it shows you how you can add data and methods to an exception.

Comment: Great explanation! +1

Comment: There's the link for the claim, the topic is called [exceptions as control flow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class InvalidAgeException extends Exception {

    public InvalidAgeException(String str) {
        super(str);
    }
}


public class MainClass {

    public List<Integer> checkAge(int ages[]) throws InvalidAgeException {
        List<Integer> invalid = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ages.length; i++) {
            if (ages[i] < 18) {
                invalid.add(ages[i]);
            } else {
                System.out.println(ages[i] + " valid age");
            }
        }

        return invalid;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidAgeException {
        int[] ages = { 19, 20, 24, 13, 27, 14 };

        List<Integer> invalid = checkAge(ages);

        if (invalid.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No invalid ages!");
        } else {
            throw new InvalidAgeException("The following ages are invalid! " + invalid);
        }
    }
}
```

The following uses java 8 to find invalid ages. This is just an alternative. This uses varargs and also allows you define the minimum age incase you want to change it.

```
    private static List<Integer> findInvalid(int minimumInclusive, int... ages) {
        return IntStream.of(ages).filter(age -> age <= minimumInclusive).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers and comments already provided by experts are great. This answer does not, in any way, competes with any of the already provided answers and comments. I am answering just to let you know that in case you need multiple `Exception` objects, you can create a list of the Exception objects as given below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class InvalidAgeException extends Exception {
    public InvalidAgeException(String str) {
        super(str);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return this.getMessage();
    }
}

public class MainClass {

    public static ArrayList<InvalidAgeException> checkAge(int ages[]) throws InvalidAgeException {
        List<InvalidAgeException> expList = new ArrayList<InvalidAgeException>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ages.length; i++) 
            if (ages[i] < 18) 
                expList.add(new InvalidAgeException(ages[i] + " invalid age"));     
        return (ArrayList<InvalidAgeException>) expList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidAgeException {
        int[] ages = { 19, 20, 24, 13, 27, 14 };
        System.out.println(checkAge(ages));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[13 invalid age, 14 invalid age]
```